# javascript Paste within this specific page?

Tags: javascript, paste

This is a specific situation:
visit http://new.cloudfile.co/transfer
click the orange "+"button lowerhand. Then with javascript:
I want to paste something already in clipboard into that popup input box, I tried:

```js
        var clipboardData = window.clipboardData; //for IE  
        if (!clipboardData) { // for chrome  
            clipboardData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData;  
        }  
window.prompt("PASTE to clipboard: Ctrl+V, Enter",clipboardData);
```

also tried:

```js
 var tmp1=document.getElementById("trsfr-link");
 tmp1.select();
document.execCommand("paste");
```

Both the above 2 methods are inside "$( document ).ready(function() {...}" structure, since I need to use it to click that orange + button.
Nothing happened with pasting...... I'm totally new to javascript. Any idea, please?

Comment: "I'm totally new to javascript" No, javascript has no knowledge of you. Thus the correct form would be "JavaScript is new to me".

Comment: One problem is that due to security reasons clipboard is not accessible in all browsers without using things like flash and that also has cross browser issues

Comment: Thanks. But why window.prompt("PASTE to clipboard: Ctrl+V, Enter",clipboardData) does not work?